# What is the best notation for this problem?

Tags: notation

Assume you have defined variables $A$, $B$ and $C$ in the text. There is also a defined function $f$ that applies on those variables. In addition you may have some variables such as $\kappa_A$, $\kappa_B$ and etc.

The question is, how to best express $f$ and $\kappa$ without repeating it for the three variables. I mean, I was thinking of the following solution but maybe you have a better suggestion:

"...we have $f(A)$, $f(B)$, and $f(C)$. Also we have $\kappa_A$, $\kappa_B$, and $\kappa_C$ where $f([.])$ and $\kappa_{[.]}$ are ...."

Also somebody suggested this "...where $f(\ast)$ and $\kappa_{\ast}$.

Comment: I'm curious what the context is, but $“f([{.}])”$ and $“\kappa_{[.]}”$ look weird.

Comment: it is pure mathematics. I know it is weird, but is there any other way to show that?!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

> "... we have $f(A)$, $f(B)$, and $f(C)$. Also we have $\kappa_A$, $\kappa_B$, and $\kappa_C$ where **$f(X)$ and $\kappa_X$ are ... for all $X \in \left\{ A,B,C \right\}$** ..."